# How to connect Gremlin to Neo4j database step by step?

Tags: java, neo4j, gremlin

I'm new in Gremlin.
And I want to connect Gremlin to Neo4j Database and I already tried the way to connect to Neo4j database.

```
gremlin> g = new neo4jgraph[EmbeddedGraphDatabase[C:\Users\Olivia Stella\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb]]
```

and before it's connected to Gremlin, an error message shown up:

```
java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init> Warning: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

Note:

> -Gremlin 2.4.0
>
> -Java SDK 7
>
> -Neo4j 2.0.1

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace? There is certainly an option with the gremlin shell to show these? Please note that for Neo4j 2.0.x you need tinkerpop 2.5-SNAPSHOT (afaik).

Comment: Hi Michael, I just found your article about Neo4j support Gremlin again -> https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin but after I run mvn clean package, it return some errors messages like at `com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.console.Console.<init><Console.java:58>...`

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: share the stacktrace otherwise we cannot understand what's the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry @MarcoCI. I'm new in Gremlin. how to print the full stacktrace in cmd so I can share it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't look like valid Gremlin syntax from the REPL:

```
gremlin> g = new Neo4jGraph('/tmp/neo4j')
==>neo4jgraph[EmbeddedGraphDatabase [/tmp/neo4j]]
gremlin> g.addVertex([name:'stephen'])
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V.map
==>{name=stephen}
gremlin> g.commit()
==>null
gremlin> g.shutdown()
==>null
gremlin> g = new Neo4jGraph('/tmp/neo4j')
==>neo4jgraph[EmbeddedGraphDatabase [/tmp/neo4j]]
gremlin> g.V.map                         
==>{name=stephen}
```

Alternatively, if you have an existing `org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService` instance that you would like to use you can pass that into the `Neo4jGraph` constructor instead of the path to where the db files are (or where you would like them to be).

Comment: Thank you stephen. It works. But where can I find `/tmp/neo4j`? and where can I find `org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService`? And how to change `/tmp/neo4j` to `C:\Users\Olivia Stella\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb`. Thank you.

Comment: looks like you are on windows, so i would assume that it's at `c:\tmp\neo4j`.  In your case, I would try to point it at: `new Neo4jGraph('C:\Users\Olivia Stella\Documents\Neo4j\')`

Comment: Oh yeah stephen, why can I not use the database after I made it? It says `Unable to lock store. Are you running another Neo4j process against this database?`

Comment: You can't open a Neo4j instance if already open elsewhere.  As the message states, the db is "locked".  Try `Neo4jHaGraph` if you want to do that: https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Neo4jHa-Implementation

Comment: thank you for the reference but are there other ways to make the db unlocked?

Comment: I presume there is an existing JVM process connected to that graph in that directory.  Shutdown that process and then re-execute the command to open the db in the Gremlin REPL.

Comment: But it's weird, I already shutdown the JVM process but it still gets error. It says `Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, C:\Users\Olivia Stella\Documents\Neo4j\DB_Gremlin`. I'm still confused how gremlin works with Neo4j database, should I do this `g = new Neo4jGraph('C:\Users\Olivia Stella\Documents\Neo4j\DB_Gremlin')` everytime I want to connect to and use Neo4j Database? Need more explaination.

Comment: I updated my code sample.  Note that I add a vertex, commit and shutdown the graph.  When I want to use it again, I create a new instance of `g` and can then access data I put into it previously. You shouldn't be running Neo4j Server when you try to connect with Gremlin unless you are connecting with `Neo4jHaGraph` as `Neo4jGraph` assumes a single process interacting with the graph at any time.  Neo4j Server would be a second process attempting to use that directory and therefore you would expect errors.

Comment: great. So if I want to run gremlin together with Neo4j Server so I can see what I have made in database through neo4j web browser ui, I should connect with Neo4jHaGraph? I asked other ways except Neo4jHaGraph because I see your docs that it should be implemented with java. Or maybe I misunderstood. I'm still confused with these 2 codes that are <dependency>...</dependency> and Map<String.. Where should I put them so I can use Neo4jHaGraph?

Comment: The dependency information is for Maven.  It has nothing to do with the Gremlin REPL and instantiating a Neo4jHAGraph within it.  Construct a map instance just as it is shown in the docs with your appropriate Neo4j HA Server instance and give it to Neo4jHAGraph on construction.  You may need to spend some time reading up more on Neo4j HA and learning about the Java ecosystem before progressing much further.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your explaination stephen.